# Why isn't string splitting after last open parenthesis?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to split the string by the last occurrence of the left ("(") parenthesis, but for some reason, R and `stringr::str_split` isn't recognizing this.

Ideally, I want the string to split the `(PP)`.

Any ideas?

```r
library(stringr)

## Doesn't Work
str_split("Ben Meyers (1), Hank Crone (1) (PP)", "\\([^\\(]*$", simplify = TRUE)
#>      [,1]                              [,2]
#> [1,] "Ben Meyers (1), Hank Crone (1) " ""

## Works
str_split("Ben Meyers (1), Hank Crone (1) (PP)", "\\(", simplify = TRUE)
#>      [,1]          [,2]              [,3]  [,4] 
#> [1,] "Ben Meyers " "1), Hank Crone " "1) " "PP)"
```

Created on 2018-12-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Use `"\\((?=[^(]*$)"`

Comment: Woah. Why did that work? If you turn that into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
"\\((?=[^(]*$)"
```

The pattern is `\((?=[^(]*$)`

- `\(` - a `(`
- `(?=[^(]*$)` - the positive lookahead that requires 0 or more chars other than `(` up to the end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

R test:

```
> library(stringr)
> str_split("Ben Meyers (1), Hank Crone (1) (PP)", "\\((?=[^(]*$)", simplify = TRUE)
     [,1]                              [,2] 
[1,] "Ben Meyers (1), Hank Crone (1) " "PP)"
```

If you want to "trim" the whitespace from the element before the last open parenthesis, you may add `\s*` at the start (to match 0 or more whitespaces):

```
"\\s*\\((?=[^(]*$)"
 ^^^^
```

See the [**regex demo** online](https://regex101.com/r/PlYiYV/1).